# How to organize multiple url fetch calls with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, urlfetch

I should perform thousands of URL fetch calls during the day. All calls are the same, just parameters changes - `way` and `date`.

Currently I use multiple cron entries to execute such calls:

```
- description: get data
  url: /admin/getdata?d=way1,way2,way3,way4,...,way12
  schedule: every day 8:30

- description: get data
  url: /admin/getdata?d=way13,way14,way15,way16,...,way24
  schedule: every day 8:40

...

- description: get data
  url: /admin/getdata?d=way99,way100,way101,way102,...,way123
  schedule: every day 9:20
```

Then in my `getdata` handler I parse the `d` parameter received and perform multiple `urlfetch`es:

```
for date_ in dates:
    for way in d:
        response = urlfetch.Fetch('http://example.com?way='+way+'&date='+date_, deadline=60, headers=headers, follow_redirects=True)
```

But it doesn't help me a lot - still 60 seconds given for the cron job is not enough.

I was thinking about running cron job each ten minutes, but I should store somewhere possible `way`s and `date`s, mark already executed requests, then reset it (to be able to execute all again next day).

Is there any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, one cron job which spawns taskqueued jobs for all the other urls.  That can be done in the default module, for free.  I would set a `countdown` parameter, to space them out, to not spawn up too many instances. Simplifies app.yaml as well.

Comment: Thanks. But what `batch` means in GAE documentation - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push? It says 'Maximum number of tasks that can be added in a batch: 100'. Can I have just 100 tasks?

Comment: Yes, you can set the batch.  That throttles the rate at which they are executed.  If you set it to 100, you will have 100 tasks running at the same time. That will almost certainly spawn up some new instances for your app, which will push you out of the free quota.  But, if you don't mind a small cost, it will work very well.

Comment: Finally I've chosen your approach since when I tried to use Modules API (what @AndreiVolgin suggested), the given (within free app) instance hours were not enough for my task.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to have just one cron job per day that fetches all urls. All you need to do is to target this cron-job at a backend instance, which does not have a time limit.

Use [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) to create such an instance, and add a "target" setting to your cron job.

Comment: Andrei, thanks. Are you talking about free GAE app? Where can I read about it?

Comment: I added a link to the Modules API.